# PhoneGap create gallery, store pictures to it

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

I have been trying to find a solution to save the pictures i take using phonegap camera API to a gallery of my choice. The phonegap docs say that it should ignore any option of opening a gallery in Android, but nowhere has it mentioned how to create new galleries if the required one doesn't exist in other platforms?

Or how to store the pictures captured to the gallery of your choice??

Comment: im not sure if creating galleries is possible with phonegap, unless u modify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send image from your javascript to you native code (**Obj-C**, **Java**) and save it to device by native tools.